# PDF editing. Add an increasing number next to a specific value

Tags: python

I have PDF drawings of target locations on a map. Each target location has a constant value next to it. Let's say "A"
I want to add an increasing value say "101"+1 next to each A so that I can give each location a unique identifier.
This way a crew member can say "at location 103" and I know where on the map he/she is.
right now I am manually editing PDFs to add these values which sucks, wondering if I can automate

I am using PyPDF2 and reportlab but struggling to get the location of each "A" and to print the new values

Comment: it does not have to cover the symbol A. just find and save each A location in a dictionary and then print "101" at X to the right of each A location. Still can't seem to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Consider using PyMuPDF instead. Will let you find correct locations including whatever text font properties plus color.

At each identified location boundary box, append your unique id ..., or add an appropriate annotation as KJ indicated.